# Jquery Galleryview

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a site that requires a jquery [Galleryview](http://spaceforaname.com/panels.html) now I have everything set up but my images are not showing.

**here is my header code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.timers-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.galleryview-1.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#photos').galleryView({

 panel_width: 506,
    panel_height: 275,
    transition_speed: 1500,
    transition_interval: 5000,
    nav_theme: 'dark',
    border: '1px solid white',
    pause_on_hover: true


 });
</script>
```

**My gallery code:**

```
<div id="photos" class="galleryview">
<div class="panel">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/condo-one/1.jpg" alt="image1" />
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/condo-one/2.jpg" alt="image1" />
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/condo-one/3.jpg" alt="image1" /> 
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/condo-one/4.jpg" /> 
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/condo-one/5.jpg" />    
  </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that the images are not showing but it's the correct path view the site demo [here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/condo-oasis/condos-for-rent/condoasis-one/) please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out the solution which was pretty stupid of me.

The script was missing :

```
$(document).readygalleryView({

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we go down any other route, are you sure that all your script URLs in your header are valid and loading correctly (there's a typo with an `=` sign in one of your `src`'s).

Comment: Yes they the correct path and all of it are loading correctly

Answer (score 0):

One thing is your paths for your jQuery libraries are inconsistent; fix those and use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if all your jQuery and images are loading.

Comment: Images 2 and 3 load for me, it's just image 1 doesn't load on document ready.